# Android Jsoup get a YouTubeVideo ID form an selected Element

Tags: android, jsoup, element

Rss String:

```html
<description>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%39s2zWNZydiI&amp;h=aAQEbhn3&amp;s=1" id="" title="" target="" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.referrer_log(this, &quot;https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=9s2zNZydiI&quot;, and so on ....... "> 
</description>
```

Android Parser Code:

```js
Element imgElement = docHtml.select("a").first();
                    if (imgElement != null) {


                        IDContent = imgElement2.attr("onclick");

                    }
```

**Question:**

How can I get the Youtube ID between the "watch?v=" and ";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [URLDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode the url string.

Then use a regular expression to extract VideoID from url

```
public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl){
  String video_id="";
  if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 &&  youtubeUrl.startsWith("http")){ 
    String expression = "^.*((youtu.be"+ "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var  regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()){
      String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
      if(groupIndex1!=null && groupIndex1.length()==11)
        video_id = groupIndex1;
     }
   }
  return video_id;
}
```